# Jupyter Notebook - .ipynb files - opening as plain text - No longer interactive notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Windows 10 machine with VirtualBox, Linux Mint 18, running Jupyter Notebook.

I have successfully generated 20+ notebooks and viewed them running html, and processed still images.

I changed the viewer to view the source code of the page, and cannot figure out how to switch back to the notebook view.

Now when I click on my .ipynb files, I see the plain text, but no longer am viewing the file as an interactive Jupyter notebook.

I've tried changing the lower bar setting to JSON and HTML, but that does not seem to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, Jupyter notebook was not running when I clicked on the .ipynb file.

Because the .ipynb files are stored in plain text format, Mint just opened the file as plain text, rather than giving me an error message saying "cannot open .ipynb files."

PROBLEM SOLVED